# Divs arrangement

Tags: html, css

i want to create an html page ,where on the left top side will be an image (400x200) ,exact below the image a rectangle div(same width with image and height 50px) and exact on  the right of the image  another rectangle as a button(same height with image an width 50px) .
On the right size of the page i want 3 smaller rectangle divs as buttons(100x50) (one next to the other).
How can i achieve this? .I thought of creating two containers and put the image and the 2 divs to the one on the left and the rest 3 divs to the right.
However something is missing, especially if the resolution is lower or i adjust the window the arrangement is awful .Which approach  is better when the resolution is smaller. The position should be for the left container absolute?Thanks in advance.
I 've created this

```css
#container1 {width:50%;height:300px;float:left;margin-left:30px;margin-top:20px;}
#container1 a{ text-decoration:none;}

#container2 {width:40%;height:300px;float:right;margin-left:50px;margin-top:50px;}
#container2 a{ text-decoration:none;}
#col1 { float:left; margin:5px;font-size:14pt; border:1px;width:400px;height:200px;border-radius:5px;}

.col2 { float:left;background-color:rgb(17, 83, 151); margin:10px; border:1px ;margin-top:75px;width:155px;height:70px;}
#col3 { position:relative;float:left;background-color:rgb(17, 83, 151); margin:5px;margin-right:5px;font-size:14pt; border:1px ;width:110px;height:200px;border-radius:5px;}
.int {text-align:center;border 1px;font-family:segoe UI;font-size:14pt;color:white;padding-top:5px;margin:15px;}
.int2 {text-align:center;border 1px;font-family:segoe ui;font-size:14pt; color:white;padding-top:50px;margin:3px;}
#col4 {position:absolute;float:left;clear:both;background-color:rgb(17, 83, 151); margin:5px;font-size:14pt; border:1px ;width:400px;height:80px;border-radius:5px;}

.button {padding-top:30px; padding-left:10px; color:white;  font-size:10pt; font-family:Segoe UI; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div id="container1">

   <div id="col1" class="col">
  <img id="img" src="http://ima.gs/transparent/400x200.png"">
   </div>
   
   <div id="col3">
 <a href=#"><div class="int2">button 1</div></a>
   </div>
   
   <div id="col4">
  <a href=#"><div class="int">button 2 </div></a>

   </div>
   
  </div>   

<div id="container2">


 <div class="col2"><a href="#"><div class="button">button 3</div></a>
 
 </div>
 

 
 <div class="col2"><a href="#"><div class="button" style="padding-top:30px;">button 4</div></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col2"><a href="#"><div class="button" style="padding-top:30px;">button5</div></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm noticing is that you're floating elements and using margins. Switch to padding and this will make your life much easier as far as width calculations goes:

```
#container1 {width:50%;height:300px;float:left;padding-left:30px;margin-top:20px;}

#container2 {width:50%;height:300px;float:right;padding-left:50px;margin-top:50px;}
```

As long as border-box is being used in your css, padding eats up the inside of containers instead of adding it to the outside. Basically your containers were 50% + 30px margin. I changed it to 50% width with an inset 30px padding. Now you can do easy math instead of accounting for a margin.

Comment: Well i fixed this:  http://jsfiddle.net/alipkok/v7vkfo21/

However, i cannot find a way on how to make Column1 and Column2 positions fixed on window resize.
I was thinking that an idea would be to have auto size for the image size but it does not work.Moreover buttons before change line, overlap with container 1.On purpose i added borders.Any idea, would be welcome.Thank you